# a bash script will work on cron

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron

I have this script working well on putty (Php server)

It should move all directories with names like 2017-05-05 from /home/reservation to /home/reservation/inmo

Could you help me to get it working as a cronjob ?

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in $(ls /home/reservation |egrep "^20??-??-??");do mv /home/reservation/$i /home/reservation/inmo;done
```

Comment: call the bash file from cron? `0 0 * * * /path/to/myBASH.sh`

Comment: There are multiple tutorials you can find by Googling. For example: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: Hello thank you very much. I'm with OVH and the cronjob is very strange. It deactivate it after some attempt !

Comment: sounds like you may need to talk to your host then

Comment: He asked me to use a php file instead of .sh :( :(

Comment: if you can make a runnable php script, then you still can apply it with crontab.

Comment: nothing in their you cant do with php, maybe they dont allow bash

Comment: You don't provide enough information of your server, however, I don't think that a proper setting linux will have this kinda constraint.

Comment: The same script in the .sh file will it work in a php file ?` #! /bin/bash
for i in $(ls /home/reservation |egrep "^20??-??-??");do mv /home/reservation/$i /home/reservation/inmo;done`

Comment: no you will have to write valid php

Comment: "He asked me to use a php file instead of .sh" - sounds like you need to speak to a different host.

Answer (score 1):

For a runnable php script, it should contains `#!/path/to/php` in first line. And according to the comment by @symcbean, you should run `chmod +x /path/to/your_php_script` to make the script executable.

---

For user who have privileged to run this script, simply typing command

```
$ crontab -e
```

And adding your worked and runnable script as below:

```
# every day 23:59 will run this script
$ 59 23 * * * /path/to/your_php_script

# every January 2rd 23:59 will run this script
$ 59 23 2 1 * /path/to/your_php_script

# every friday 23:59 will run this script
$ 59 23 * * 5 /path/to/your_php_script

# every 5 minutes will run this script
$ */5 * * * * /path/to/your_php_script
```

---

If the admin **disable crond** in the server, the alternative way you can try is running your php script periodically as a daemon process.

Comment: In addition to setting the first line to '#!/usr/bin/php' you also need to set the relevant execute bits on the file (not required when running via a webserver).

Comment: or just call via php cli `59 23 * * * php /path/to/your_php_script.php` then you dont need either